# 3 tails in a row in a series

Tags: probability

The dealer flips a perfectly symmetrical coin $30$ times. If you get $3$ tails in a row, you win. If $3$ tails do not fall out in a row, the dealer wins. Calculate the probability of your winning.

There are $2^{30}$ outcomes in total. Initially, I counted the number of outcomes of the form $...XTTTX...$, where $X=H, T$. The number of such outcomes was calculated as follows: $2^{30-3} \cdot (30-3) = 27 \cdot 2^{27}$, as it doesn’t matter to us what will stand in other places in the series, and the triple of tails itself can be moved by shifting its beginning from $1$ to $27$.

However, dividing this number of favorable outcomes by the total number of outcomes results in a number greater than $1$. I realized that the reason is that if there are more than $3$ tails in a series, the number of possible shifts becomes less than $27$.
That is, for example, the situation when the first element on the left in the sequence $..TTT..$ is $T$ must degenerate into another case. However, then it becomes unclear to me how to correctly reduce situations with more than $3$ consecutive tails in order to subtract them from the total number of favorable outcomes.

Comment: You could use recursion to determine the probability that the dealer wins, then subtract that probability from $1$.

Comment: I thought about it, but it seemed to me that this way of solving is even more complicated. For example, it should be taken into account that the HTTHTTH situation is suitable for the dealer, but the HTTTHTH situation is not suitable. That is, it already becomes important in what order the tails fall out.

Comment: There is a simple recursion here...a bad string (for you) must begin with one of $H,TH, TTH$.  Thus $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$.  No useful closed form solution but it's easy to work with small strings, as here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $hh[i]$ be the probability that after $i>1$ coin flips, we never got three tails in a row, and the last two flips were `HH`. Define $ht[i]$, $th[i]$, $tt[i]$ similarly. Then the answer to the question is $1 - hh[30] - ht[30] - th[30] - tt[30]$. These probabilities can be computed recursively as in this C++ program:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    double hh[31], ht[31], th[31], tt[31];
    hh[2] = ht[2] = th[2] = tt[2] = 0.25;
    for(int i = 3; i <= 30 ; ++i) {
        hh[i] = ht[i] = 0.5 * hh[i - 1] + 0.5 * th[i - 1];
        th[i] = 0.5 * ht[i - 1] + 0.5 * tt[i - 1];
        tt[i] = 0.5 * ht[i - 1];
    }
    printf("result: %f\n", 1 - hh[30] - ht[30] - th[30] - tt[30]);
}
```

The output is `result: 0.907846`.